# Upgrading App bundle on MacOS which has daemon service/process running

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have developed an app bundle MyApp which has daemon process my-daemon-process' and plist file registered appropriately under '/Library/LaunhDaemons/com.my-app.plist'.

Now, I have newer version of the app bundle which upgrades 'my-daemon-process' also. I am trying to upgrade it while 'my-daemon-process' from installed version is already running. Post upgrade, it goes into cyclic crash.

If I manually unload and load the service using 'launchctl unload/load' it works fine.

Note: both versions of the 'my-daemon-process' refer to different versions of same 3rd party shared library.

What am I doing wrong here? Any insights into what MacOS does internally while app upgrade will also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured this out eventually.

The way MacOS handles upgrade of running package is: it replaces all the files and scripts but does NOT unload the earlier loaded plist file. New process/daemon is launched under already loaded/cached plist copy which is from (now) earlier build.

Issue here was plist from older and new version differ. Earlier I was using DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and NOT packaging libsqlite3 under /Applications/MyApp/Contents/Library. In newer version, this was changed to remove DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (switched to using @rpath) and include libsqlite3 which is stripped down version.

MacOS internally maintains some meta-data using libsqlite whenever any process within app is launched. Due to influence of previous plist and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, it was looking into my shipped libsqlite as opposed to full version under "/System/Library/Frameworks/..." and thus the crash.

Comment: I am yet to figure out how to **refresh loaded copy of plist file**. Many comments say `defaults` utility does it but I did not get any success out of it. Tried it on MacOS 10.10 as well as 10.11